# Sitefinity Text line breaks

Tags: sitefinity

In my model I have text with  tag where I would like to replace it with a html 
 tag. I did search and show that using Html.Encode may work but that didnt work.

> is there another way to do this in the cshtml file?

```
@Html.Encode(Model.Desceiption).Replace("<cr>", "<br>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
@Html.Raw(...)
```